# How do I open a file in its default program

Tags: c, windows, winapi

How do I programmatically open a file in its default program (I'm using Windows XP).

For example, opening *.txt will open the file in notepad.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

the function [ShellExecute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762153%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Has been provided for this.